# JavaKerberos not using provided username and password while connecting to MS SQL DB

Tags: java, sql-server, kerberos, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying use JavaKerberos with provided username and password to connect to Ms SQL DB. followed this https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/66# and using mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar, it should use provided username and password in connection string to connect to DB, but its trying to connect with AD username.
below is my java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            // Establish the connection. 
            SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
            ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
            ds.setAuthenticationScheme("JavaKerberos");
            ds.setServerName("myserver");
            ds.setPortNumber(1433); 
            ds.setDatabaseName("users");
            ds.setUser("user");
            ds.setPassword("password");
            con = ds.getConnection();
        // Execute a stored procedure that returns some data.
                    cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");
                    cstmt.setInt(1, 50);
                    rs = cstmt.executeQuery();

                // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
                while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE: " + rs.getString("LastName") + 
                            ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
                        System.out.println("MANAGER: " + rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + 
                            ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
                        System.out.println();
                }
            }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

also set the .java.login.config as below and using mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar (download from http://www.java2s.com/example/jar/m/download-mssqljdbc622jre8jar-file.html)

```
cat ~/.java.login.config
SQLJDBCDriver {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useTicketCache=true;
};
```

I'm getting below error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '{my AD user name}'. ClientConnectionId:3a3d0513-1f87-42d8-a799-b9f43374e1a6
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:4014)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4292)
```

looks like its not using the provided username and password to establish connection, did I miss anything here? please let me know how to solve this.